# MYSQL: how to pass column values in select stmt into a function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've a procedure of the following form:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure cl.getcoords(lat FLOAT(15,12), lon FLOAT(15,12), distance int)
    BEGIN


    declare tlat FLOAT(15,12);
    declare tlon FLOAT(15,12);
    declare tcoslat FLOAT(20,16);
    SELECT lat, lon, cos_lat into tlat, tlon, tcoslat FROM cl.mrkrs WHERE cl.getcoordsdistance(lat, lon, tlat, tlon, tcoslat, distance) IS TRUE LIMIT 100;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm not getting any results when i call this procedure. What am doing wrong?

Comment: What data is involved? Why is this a stored procedure? Have you looked at the [MySQL Spatial Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html)?

Comment: Probably there is not a single record that would match the where criteria. There is no way we can tell why based on the question.

Comment: lat and lon are latitude and longitude and I don't have access to the db schema to do any changes.

Comment: When i call the function manually with values in table ..it works. My question is this the correct way to do it and why am not getting any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did the following to get what i was looking for:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getcoords`(lat FLOAT(15,12), lon FLOAT(15,12), distance int)
BEGIN


--    declare tlat FLOAT(15,12);
--    declare tlon FLOAT(15,12);
--    declare tcoslat FLOAT(20,16);
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT lat , lon , cos_lat FROM cl.mrkrs WHERE cl.getcoordsdistance(',lat,',' ,lon,', lat, lon, cos_lat,',distance,') IS TRUE LIMIT 100');
    prepare stmt1 from @s;
    execute stmt1;
    deallocate prepare stmt1;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass like that --

```
SELECT "abc" AS column1 FROM dual;
```